# Error "open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified" when using Gitlab Runner docker-windows executor

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci-runner, windows-server-2022

I am trying to use Gitlab Runner (v15.9.1) to run CI jobs on a Windows Server 2022 (10.0.20348) VM, using the docker-windows executor. The Docker version is 24.0.2. I have set up a simple test job, but when I run it on Gitlab I get the following error:

`ERROR: error during connect: this error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/_ping": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.`

Going to the command line on the target VM and entering

`docker run hello-world`

downloads the hello-world image and runs it as expected, so Docker *is* running. I have also verified that it is set to run Windows containers. The Services window shows that the gitlab-runner service is also running.

The config.toml for the Gitlab runner:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "MyGitlabDockerRunner"
  url = "https://gitlab.myorg.com"
  id = XXXX
  token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  token_obtained_at = 2023-07-20T11:12:46Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker-windows"
  shell = "powershell"
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:lts2022"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["c:\\cache"]
    shm_size = 0
    helper_image = "gitlab/gitlab-runner-helper:x86_64-v${CI_RUNNER_VERSION}-servercore21H1"
```

The full output of the Gitlab CI job:

[Gitlab Job Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVbky.png)

Looking at the Event Viewer on the target VM, each attempt to run the job produces the following four errors from docker:

```
exec's CreateProcess() failed [error=container c4425506999705510fa0f996b957346de9dbdf0be51f7fde0951ee2c59f207bb encountered an error during hcs::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The user name or password is incorrect. (0x52e)
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail: onecore\vm\compute\management\orchestration\vmhostedcontainer\processmanagement.cpp(173)\vmcomputeagent.exe!00007FF7B0C1F64D: (caller: 00007FF7B0BC4AE7) Exception(6) tid(4e0) 8007052E The user name or password is incorrect.
    CallContext:[\Bridge_ProcessMessage\VmHostedContainer_ExecuteProcess] 
 Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] namespace=moby container=c4425506999705510fa0f996b957346de9dbdf0be51f7fde0951ee2c59f207bb exec=0e7d8872a9f8a8ee0e9ecc3ee82dab435f682e705beaf8fb1adf9a25be4414c8 module=libcontainerd]
```

```
Error running exec 0e7d8872a9f8a8ee0e9ecc3ee82dab435f682e705beaf8fb1adf9a25be4414c8 in container: container c4425506999705510fa0f996b957346de9dbdf0be51f7fde0951ee2c59f207bb encountered an error during hcs::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The user name or password is incorrect. (0x52e)
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail: onecore\vm\compute\management\orchestration\vmhostedcontainer\processmanagement.cpp(173)\vmcomputeagent.exe!00007FF7B0C1F64D: (caller: 00007FF7B0BC4AE7) Exception(6) tid(4e0) 8007052E The user name or password is incorrect.
    CallContext:[\Bridge_ProcessMessage\VmHostedContainer_ExecuteProcess] 
 Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
```

```
exec's CreateProcess() failed [module=libcontainerd namespace=moby container=cc09b87c3a5274318322f5759d7d4da478693efeff3cc3df86763106e4918717 exec=4a1daced8f89ef9fc4fe31f62b78c19be24fb866b58fddae904f9194d7a284ec error=container cc09b87c3a5274318322f5759d7d4da478693efeff3cc3df86763106e4918717 encountered an error during hcs::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The user name or password is incorrect. (0x52e)
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail: onecore\vm\compute\management\orchestration\vmhostedcontainer\processmanagement.cpp(173)\vmcomputeagent.exe!00007FF7348AEC2D: (caller: 00007FF734854AE7) Exception(6) tid(3d8) 8007052E The user name or password is incorrect.
    CallContext:[\Bridge_ProcessMessage\VmHostedContainer_ExecuteProcess] 
 Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]]
```

```
Error running exec 4a1daced8f89ef9fc4fe31f62b78c19be24fb866b58fddae904f9194d7a284ec in container: container cc09b87c3a5274318322f5759d7d4da478693efeff3cc3df86763106e4918717 encountered an error during hcs::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The user name or password is incorrect. (0x52e)
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail: onecore\vm\compute\management\orchestration\vmhostedcontainer\processmanagement.cpp(173)\vmcomputeagent.exe!00007FF7348AEC2D: (caller: 00007FF734854AE7) Exception(6) tid(3d8) 8007052E The user name or password is incorrect.
    CallContext:[\Bridge_ProcessMessage\VmHostedContainer_ExecuteProcess] 
 Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
```

I take it these are the reason for the job failing, but I'm unclear on what user name and password are expected here and how to provide them. I have also tried with Docker running as administrator, and the result is the same.